# multi threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a program or function printValue() that prints some value. But it takes some time(say 5 min) to execute the function. So, How can I implement multithreading or some technique in python so that within that 5 min I can print the % of completion. i.e How can I achieve the following output.

```
#program starts.
#-------------- __%complete --------------#
#output_of_printValue()
#end program
```

Comment: The % of completion is called text/terminal process bar. Google it, you can find many answers and a few libraries.

Answer (score 0):

After the comment of Leonardo.Z I Google it for a bit, and I found [python-progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/) as my answer!